# Making a recursive formula for finding amount of ways to spend money on beer

Tags: recurrence-relation, recursion

So far, i've only made recursive formulas for finding simple patterns such as fibonacci, however i can't seem to get my head around this.

The information available is that there are $n$ different beers with different prices, the $i$th beer has a price $p_i$.  Students have $C$ amount of money

How would you make a recursive formula for the amount of ways students can spend exactly $C$ money on beer?

Comment: Does the order matter ? I mean does the purchase of 4, 3, 2, 4 differs from the purchase of 2, 4, 4, 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

The $n$-the beer has price $p_n$. You can use $k$ items of beer $n$, provided $k\cdot p_n\le C$. The remaining money can be used for beers $1$ to $n-1$. That gives a recursive approach.

Comment: so if i were to make that as a recursive formula it would be something like:

\begin{equation}
  N(C, i)=\begin{cases}
  N(C, i)=0 & \text{if $C=0$}\\
  N(C, i)= k \cdot p_i & \text{if $K \cdot p_n \leq C$}\\
  N(C, i)=  C-p_i & \text{if $C>0$ and $K \cdot p_n > C$ }
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

I'm actually unsure on how to formulate "$1$ to $n-1$

Answer (score 0):

My attempt is

$$
N(C)=\left\{
\begin{align}
&0&C<p_{min}\\
&1&C=p_{min}\\
&\displaystyle\sum_i N(C-p_i)&\text{other cases}
\end{align}
\right.
$$

The summation part solves your problem of going through 1 to n.

Implementing this on the computer gives correct answers.

Comment: This is wrong. Try $p_1=2,p_2=3,C=3$.

Answer (score 0):

If the order matters and the $p_k$ are distinct,

$$N(C)=\begin{cases}C=p_1\to1\\C=p_2\to1\\\cdots\\C=p_n\to1\\\text{else}\to\displaystyle\sum_{p_k\le C}N(C-p_k)\end{cases}$$